# FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied] when fetching data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on creating a serverless database using Firebase. However, I'm encountering an error whenever I attempt to fetch the data, even though my internet connection is stable and working properly.

Instead of receiving the expected data from Firestore, I got this error

**The error:**

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.0.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project find-jobs-5c4e7.firebaseapp.com.
> This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

**the configuration:**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";
import { initializeFirestore, CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_LINK
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app, {
  experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
});

export default app;
```

**data fetching code:**

```
const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const CollectionRef = collection(db, "users");

  const getList = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getDocs(CollectionRef);
      const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
      }));
      setList(filteredData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getList();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the key values in the code directly instead of using the env file. Additionally, I replaced the "getFirestore" function with "initializeFirestore". These changes successfully addressed the problem I was experiencing.